# Java access specifier issue

Tags: java, access-specifier

I am confused with access specifiers in Java.. I have a code with 2 different packages in Java.. But it displays an error every time I run it.. Here's is the code for the class which is calling the class using import from another package..

```
package p2;

import p1.Testing;

class Pqr extends Testing{ // extending the class 
    void hey(){
        System.out.println("Something");
    }
}

class Xyz{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Pqr t1 = new Pqr(); // Class from another package.
    System.out.println(t1.find("Mississippi","p"));
    t1.hey();
    }
}
```

Code for class which is being subclassed from package p1..

```
package p1;
class Testing{
    protected static boolean find(String a,String b){ // Protected specifier
        boolean ans = false;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
            String m = a.charAt(i) + "";
            if( m.equals(b)){
                ans = true;
            }
        }    

    return ans;
}

    public static void main(String args[]){

    // Main Class

    }

}
```

But when I run the code i get an error "Testing is not public in p1; cannot be accessed from outside package"..

I learned in this thread that we can use protected method between different packages but by extending it by another class.. [In Java, difference between package private, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `public class Testing` .. Your CLASS itself is not public.

Comment: You're not calling method the from a subclass. You're just calling it on *an instance of* the subclass. Except that it's static, so you're not really doing that either. `t1.find(...)` is a confusing equivalent to calling `Testing.find(...)`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Sir I read this in the thread that you can use method outside package using protected specifier..

Comment: @AkshitGupta Only from subclasses. `Xyz` is not a subclass of `Testing`, so `protected` doesn't grant access. Only `public` will.

Comment: @Andreas Sir, class pqr extends Testing making it the subclass of Testing.. Can I call Testing methods in this class?

Comment: @AkshitGupta Did you try? What happened? This is called research, and you should do research before asking questions here.

Comment: @Andreas Yes sir, i did try that and as it turns out I can call Testing methods in pqr provided the find method in Testing is either public or protected.. Otherwise it raises an error.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an access to the top-level class (in your case it's `Testing`), so you can't have an access to its members, no matter what are its access modifiers. You need to make `Testing` public to make its protected members visible from outside of its package to classes extending `Testing`. You can read more about it in Java tutorial. Here is a part about access modifier of `Testing` class:

*A class may be declared with the modifier `public`, in which case that class is visible to all classes everywhere. If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package*

And the part about your `find()` method:

*The `protected` modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.*

**But to make use of `protected` members of class contained in another package, the class itself containing it need to be visible in another packages (it needs to be `public`).**

Take a look at this Java tutorial for more informations about access modifiers:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html